# I added a rating system on my blog post but instead of stars it shows boxes

Tags: themes, css, rating

So yeah basically I hired a developer to help with writing a source code for a rating system to my blog. When I edit with Elementor it works out fine, but when I try to edit with the Gutenberg theme it shows up as boxes.

How can I make them show up as stars?

Comment: Probably because Elementor loads an external icon library. Can you paste the code generated by the page or any screenshot? It will help people to help you. At the moment, we can't help you more.

Comment: My crystal ball is on the blink. With what you have in your question I could only make wild guesses. The !&A format here works best with narrowly defined questions with great focus and clear information.